# How to test mui Modal onClose function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, material-ui

In material UI (mui) , Modal component has onClose property, whose callback fired when the component requests to be closed.
This prop enable user to close modal by clicking outside area of the modal.

```
<Modal
      open={open}
      onClose={closeFunc}
    >
...
</Modal>
```

I would like to ask in test such as jest, react test library, how could I test this functionality ?

I tried some event fire action such as `fireEvent.mouseDown(document.body);` and `userEvent.click(document.body)`, bur it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a state variable with whatever component you have, something like this

```
let [showModal, setModal] = React.useState(true);
```

and in the JSX use it like this

```
{
    showModal && <Modal open = {showModal} onClose = {() => setModal(false)}  ... />
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I would like to know how to test onClose function, not implement onclose function.
I think just mocking useState, it won't work and during the "test coverage" process, this function is not detected as having been executed.